# Creating an Index on left(date,4), is this possible? Or is there a better way to handle large data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I'm taking over an database with a table that is growing out of control.  It has transaction records for 2011, 2012, 2013 and into the future.

The table is crucial to the company's operation. But it is growing out of control with 730k records and growing with transaction being added bi-weekly.

I do not wish to alter the existing structure of the table because many existing operations depend on it, so far it has an index on the transaction ID and transaction date.  But it is becoming very cumbersome to query the table.

Would it be wise or is it even possible to index them to just the year of the transaction dates by using left(date,4) as part of the index?

EDIT: the table is not normalized (and I don't see the purpose to normalize since each row is unique to the claim number), and there are 168 fields to each record with 5 differnent "memo" fields of varchar(255).

Comment: Uh, 730k records is not that much. And I think you are confusing how dates are stored in a DB, versus their string representation when you run queries.

Comment: If really necessary you can partition the table by year, to increase performance.

Comment: @Perception 730k rows might be "a lot" if they are 8K per row and depending on application requirements. Also not everyone is on Enterprise, so partitioning is not necessarily a simple fix.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Fair enough, though I would be worried about a database design that allowed for 8k records per row. As will all things performance related, I doubt if there is an easy solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @Perception my point is simply that we can't look at "number of rows" and immediately dismiss it as "too big" or "too small"...

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to create a [Filtered Index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) - it is like uniting a group of records 
depending on specific criteria.

In your case you should create several indexed - each filtering the records for specific year.
For example:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IndexFor2013Year
    ON MyTable.BillOfMaterials (SomeDate)
    WHERE SomeDate>"2013-01-01 00:00:00" and SomeDate<"2014-01-01 00:00:00";
GO
```

Anyway, creating many indexes to a table that is often under DML operations (UPDATE/ INSERT/ DELETE) could even lead to bad performance.

You should perform some test and compare the execution plans.

And please, note that I am giving just an example - depending on what exactly is your query you should create an index. Sometimes, watching the execution plans of my queries I am proposed by the SQL Management Studio (2012) what indexes exactly could lead to better performance.

Comment: If an index was created for each year, would it be beneficial to include a condition for year within the queries?

Comment: From you question, I get the idea, that you need to know which records  refer to specific year - for example if you need to get all records for 2001 and you got filtered index for these records it should optimized your query.

Comment: Not sure if a bunch of filtered indexes, one per year, would have any benefit over a simple index on year. You're going to scan that segment in either case...